# Gamedev causing a memory leak?

Tags: bug

Lately I've been noticing very high RAM usage from Chrome. A little investigation points to Gamedev.stackexchange.com being the offending website:

[image]

This is found by using Chrome's Task Manager, by pressing Shift+Esc in the browser.

I'll admit I pretty much always have the gamedev tab open, but I restarted it earlier this week because it was up over 800 megs of RAM. I have noticed some changes to the site recently, fancy new notifications, etc.

So I'm wondering if something was introduced that would be eating RAM at a pretty good pace?

Comment: What plugins are you running?

Comment: I'm just running [AdBlock](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/adblock/gighmmpiobklfepjocnamgkkbiglidom).

Comment: @Byte56 you're using the wrong one, apparently http://www.freewaregenius.com/adblock-v-adblock-plus-two-chrome-extensions-compared/

Comment: @Lohoris Are you saying you think it's the AdBlock plugin that's suddenly causing the memory leak? Or just making conversation?

Comment: @Byte56 one of the issues raised in that article, is that "AdBlock slows down the browser when multiple tabs are opened", and this may or may not be related to the problem you encountered. In general using a shady and opportunistic clone isn't a wise choice, so if any problem arises, switching back to _the real thing_ might be a good thing to test.

Comment: I've switched from the "shady and opportunistic clone" (or clone written by an enterprising independent developer, however you want to look at it) with no change in RAM usage.

Comment: @Byte56 good to know, thanks for trying, sorry :/

Comment: Just an update. This is still happening...

Comment: Still happening... Closing the tab and reopening with Shift+Ctrl+T (to reopen last tab) brings back the tab with much less memory usage. In case anyone wants a quick workaround.